# What are Matlab commands for plotting quantized and digital signals?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB uses command "plot" for continous time signals and "stem" command for discrete time signals.

But which commands are used for plotting digital and quantized signals respectively? Can we use "stairs"command for plotting both quantized and digital signals?

Comment: You need to clarify the terms _quantized_ (quantized in y or in x?) and _digital_ (how does that differ from _quantized_? Anyway, `stairs` corresponds to [zero-order hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) (whereas `plot` is first-order hold). Run for example `stairs([4 2.5 -3 5], 'o-', 'linewidth', 1)` and try to interpret the result

Comment: Of course, everything is discrete and quantized because MATLAB executes on a digital computer. The rest is purely aesthetics. It seems like you're aware of all the main options, so give them a try and see what you think looks best.